# upload android app to google play

Tags: android, mysql

I have successfully implement android app , recently I want to publish it to google play , I know all the steps required but my database is available in localhost where I have used MySQL connected with php scripting files , reside in my PC.

IS there any way to upload database to server?

Comment: <irony>yes, for example via FTP</irony> ... but seriously you need some hosting service ... you have to: setup on your PC and make it accesible from the internet or buy some place on some server or find free hosting service

Comment: @user3904462 Did you already have a "server"? What you really need are finding some services that provide you a Linux server, so you can access DB via Internet

Answer (score 0):

you can upload your database to server, or you can use no-ip to connect your server on pc, but not secure.
the best way to upload on server.

Comment: how can I upload it to server ??

Comment: Register free server or license support PHP. After you upload to the server. Use can try hostinger host, it free